# how to extract specific data field from Javascript using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, apify

I am not sure whether this question is already asked and I am new to jquery and javascript. But, I couldnt find any answer relevant to my question. I am trying to create an [apify](https://apify.com) crawler. I need to extract specific data from following javascript

```
<script type="application/json" class="js-react-on-rails-component">
{
    "assetHost": null,
    "version": "0.0.4-855-gda76bc6\n",
    "availableLocales": [
      "de",
      "en"
    ],
    .........
    "stats": {
        "visitors": [
          {
            "domestic": 600,
            "note": "incl. 250 conference participants",
            "year": 2017,
            "total": 600,
            "structure": null,
            "latest": true
          }
        ],
        "venue": [
          {
            "total": 376,
            "domestic": 376,
            "latest": true,
            "year": 2017
          }
        ],
        "exhibitors": [
          {
            "total_indirect": 0,
            "total": 46,
            "domestic": 46,
            "latest": true,
            "year": 2017
          }
        ]
      },

      ..........
      </script>
```

I need to get the fields: `total` and `domestic` from `exhibitors` using jquery. I tried this query `(JSON.parse($('.js-react-on-rails-component').text())).exhibitors.total.text().trim()` But it didnt return anything. So, I tried to create a variable and called it on the result as follows:

```
function pageFunction(context) {
    var $ = context.jQuery;
    var exhibitor = JSON.parse($('.js-react-on-rails-component').text());
    var total = exhibitor.exhibitors.total;
    var domestic = exhibitor.exhibitors.domestic;

    if (context.request.label === "START") {
    .....
    } else { 
    var result = {
            total: total,
            domestic: domestic
        };
    return result;  
    }
}
```

But, this code also doesnt return any result.

Comment: Your query is wrong. Use `(JSON.parse($('.js-react-on-rails-component').text())).stats.exhibitors[0].total`

Comment: What error message does the console of the developer tools show you?

Comment: since you are having an json, why are you doing it in the hard way ..

Comment: @mpetrov, I tried that too, no result returned.
@ t.niese, error got is "pageFunction': Error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'JSON.parse($('.js-react-on-rails-component').text()).exhibitors.total')"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are used

***(JSON.parse($('.js-react-on-rails-component').text())).exhibitors.total.text().trim()***

If you closely look to json the exhibitors property of json is an array and you have to use **exhibitors[i].total** and **exhibitors[i].domestic** where i = 0...N;
instead of you are using exhibitors.total and exhibitors.domestic

First of all you please take your dom component to one variable for simplicity,

```
var myJson = JSON.parse($('.js-react-on-rails-component').text());

var total = myJson.stats.exhibitors[i].total;
var domestic = myJson.stats.exhibitors[i].domestic;
```

where i = 0...N;

**Edit:**

Please look at example below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>

    <div></div>    
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    
    <script type="application/json" id="myjsonscript">
        {
        "stats": {
        "visitors": [
        {
        "domestic": 600,
        "note": "incl. 250 conference participants",
        "year": 2017,
        "total": 600,
        "structure": null,
        "latest": true
        }
        ],
        "venue": [
        {
        "total": 376,
        "domestic": 376,
        "latest": true,
        "year": 2017
        }
        ],
        "exhibitors": [
        {
        "total_indirect": 0,
        "total": 46,
        "domestic": 46,
        "latest": true,
        "year": 2017
        }
        ]
        }
        }
    </script>

    
    <script id='script' type='text/javascript'>

        var myJson = JSON.parse($('#myjsonscript').text());
        $('div').html(myJson);

        var total = myJson.stats.exhibitors[0].total;
        var domestic = myJson.stats.exhibitors[0].domestic;

        alert('total:' + total);
        alert('domestic: ' + domestic);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please look on example in edit section of above answer. might be it help you

Comment: The code snippet works fine. But, in the crawler I am getting `Error invoking user-provided 'pageFunction': Error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'myJson.stats.exhibitors')`.

Comment: could you please verify that your json script is load before crawler called. if you closely look to error that your json is undefined means it not loaded before crawler and so the child property of json object not readed and it gives `Error: TypeError: undefined is not an object`

Comment: Yes, crawler is called after the json script.

Comment: Earlier the variables were declared in the beginning of the code, now I moved it inside the else clause, and now it returns data. Thank you very much.